# NLog Database Target for .net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, nlog, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to write various logs to database and to files using NLog in .net Core 2.0 . The thing is, writing logs to files working perfectly fine. But I always get following error when writing logs to database:

> 2018-01-10 08:48:29.5666 Error Error initializing target 'Database Target[db]'. Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SqlClient' from assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c'.
>           at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepalive)
>           at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
>           at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>           at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
>           at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.SetConnectionType()
>           at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.InitializeTarget()
>           at NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration)

But I have **System.Data.SqlClient** in my project as follow:

```cs
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus.Core" Version="1.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0-beta3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.5.0-rc03" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.5.0-rc2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0-preview1-25914-04" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My NLOG code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="info" internalLogFile="C:\*****\Log2\asdaf.log">
<targets>
    <target
        xsi:type="File"
        name="allfile"
        fileName="C:\*****\Logs\${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception}" >
    </target> 

    <target xsi:type="Database" name="db">
        <commandText>INSERT INTO [LogEntries](TimeStamp, Message, Level, Logger) VALUES(getutcdate(), @msg, @level, @logger)</commandText>
        <parameter name="@msg" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
        <connectionString>*****</connectionString>
    </target>

    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allOutputs" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

I searched for this issue on Github but none of the solutions worked for me. And getting System.Data.SqlClient from Nuget should be enough but unfortunately, Mr. Nlog.config want someting else and I couldn't find out what.

Comment: Just because the package is in the nuget packages.config doesn't necessarily mean it's in your project. Your top level .csproj project should also include a `PackageReference` to `System.Data.SqlClient`. You can also check the bin folder after a build to see if the DLL is present.

Comment: My .csproj says `System.Data.SqlClient` exist.

Comment: Also, there is `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` in bin folder. It looks like to me project have it but NLog can't find it.

Comment: My guess would be that the `<dbProvider>` value is not quite right. NLog seems to try and find it as a resource of its own assembly (as stated by the error message) while it could find it as resource in the _calling_ assembly. Maybe the [docs](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) can help?

Comment: ^^ There is a [paragraph](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#connection-options) which explicitly has a possible solution if encountering exactly the error you have: _"Example of using a fully qualified name with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (for dotnet core 2.0):

dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60""_ So you need to find the  equivalent to that for System.Data.SqlClient and use that.

Comment: I thought it could be becasue of provider. But I am using `System.Data.SqlClient` and wherever I searched all of them wrote provider like either `<dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>` or `provider="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was because I wrote`<dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>` for my database target. It looks like someone should update the docs.

By the way, I don't know why deleting dbProvider worked for me.

The worked code is as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="info" internalLogFile="C:\Users\maliozt\source\MyProjects\MapApplication\MapApplication\Log2\asdaf.log">
<targets>
    <target
    xsi:type="File"
    name="mapFile"
    fileName="C:\Users\maliozt\source\MyProjects\MapApplication\MapApplication\Logs\${shortdate}.log"
    layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId.Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception}" >
    </target>

    <target 
    xsi:type="Database" 
    name="mapDataBase">
        <commandText>INSERT INTO MapApplication.dbo.LogEntries(TimeStamp, Message, Level, Logger) VALUES(GETDATE(), @message, @level, @logger)</commandText>
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <!--<dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>-->
        <connectionString>Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False</connectionString>
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="mapFile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="mapDataBase" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: it is not working for me in case of oracle database. can you help me for same.

Comment: I would want to but I don't have enough Oracle knowledge. Maybe you need to write something different rather than `connectionString`.

Comment: Removing the dbProvider only works for Sql Server, because Sqlclient is the default provider. That is also why it won't work for Oracle. For Oracle you need to provide dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess". See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target.

Comment: After trying a custom target and other options, this one is the only solution for me to work with NLog and EF7 in a NET Core 7 project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case,  I found out that the error came from the table name

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Journal'

I've just removed the 'dbo' and it works.